# Code generation between JSP <-> Swing

Tags: java, swing, jsp, code-generation

Is there any tool that can convert already programmed Swing J2SE into JSP J2EE shell?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such tool. Although you might found some attempts to do it, desktop and WEB paradigms are way too different to have a tool that converts between between them properly.

If you absolutely must run your APP on a WEB environment, you might find easier to convert your Swing application into a Web Applet. It's not the same though. An Applet is basically a Swing application running inside a browser. Not a WEB-WEB application.

Comment: Converting it to Java Web Start application is a smaller (and better) step than applet. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/